# Codeigniter 4 View Cell Parameters not passing through

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Code in the view, this is being copied straight from the docs and is not working.

```
// app -> Cells -> DropdownCell.php

 namespace App\Cells;

use CodeIgniter\View\Cells\Cell;

class DropdownCell extends Cell
{
    protected $surveys; 
   
    public function courses($params): string
    {
        $this->surveys = model('SurveyModel');
        $courses = $this->surveys->getUserCourses(auth()->user()); 
        $data['items'] = []; 

        foreach ($courses as $c) {
            $data['items'][] = ['id' => $c->id, 'title' => $c->title];
        }
        return view('components/dropdown',$data);
 
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?= view_cell('DropdownCell::courses', ['type' => 'test']) ?>
```

I am getting an error:

> Too few arguments to function App\Cells\Dropdown::courses(), 0 passed

I can't see what is going wrong with this? The dropdown cell has been made with Spark as per the doc guidelines. This is being served by a controller extending BaseController.

I should add that the view cell works fine if I don't use parameters, I would just like to use them...

Comment: what is your current CI4.x version?

Comment: @Vickel version 4.4.1

Comment: *The dropdown cell has been made with Spark*: there have been some updates/fixes concerning Spark in the [latest CI 4.4.2 release](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to use the logic behind a 'simple cell' however the method I found that worked was following the instructions for 'computed cell'

Comment: You used 'simple cell' methodology. If you remove the `use CodeIgniter\View\Cells\Cell;` and `extends Cell` parts (which are from 'computed cell' methodology) it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should modify your `show` method in your view cell:

```php
public function show(array $params = []): string
{
    return "<div class=\"alert alert-{$params['type']}\">{$params['message']}</div>";
}
```

By adding the `$params = []` in the method signature, you provide default values to the `$params` array. This allows the method to be called without passing any parameters, and it will work with the default values you've set. However, you can still pass parameters to customize the view cell as needed, as you were trying to do in your view.

Your view code should work as expected:

```php
<?= view_cell('DropdownCell::show', ['type' => 'success', 'message' => 'The user has been updated.']) ?>
```

Make sure you have saved your view cell with the updated show method signature, and you should no longer encounter the "Too few arguments" error.

In your code, you're using the namespace `App\Cells\Dropdown`, but your view cell is named `DropdownCell`. Ensure that the namespace and class name match

Comment: I have already tried this and when I do this there is no data still in $params

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct namespace for your view cell. Check [Namespace Omission](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/view_cells.html#id4)

Comment: I’m following the guidelines for Namespace Omission already. Unfortunately the arguments are still not being passed through.

Comment: share some more source code.